# Troubleshoot SQL FCI

Tags: sql-server, clustering, failover-cluster-instance

I have just installed a Failover Cluster Instance (FCI) which was running ok. I then had to change the service accounts that the services were using and for some reason that I haven't been able to figure out, the Resource group (Role) now runs only partially.

The services all run only on the owning node but only the Browser running on the secondary node. If I reboot the machine and resources transfer to the secondary node, the same thing happens. If I try to manually start the services on the secondary node, they don't run.

Does anyone have any ideas please?

Comment: What process did you follow to change the service account?

Comment: I changed them in SSCM

Answer (score 1):

> The services all run only on the owning node but only the Browser running on the secondary node.

Yes, that's how FCI's work. Only the owning node should bring the services online. WSFC runs on a shared nothing model.

> [...] the Resource group (Role) now runs only partially.

Which means not all resources are online. Which resources aren't online? We don't know, you have to tell us.

Comment: thanks for your time. I was able to resolve this issue by removing the Microsoft CEIP resource in the Failover Cluster Manager. Once removed, the Cluster returned to running fully and no longer partially in Failover Cluster Manager. SQL services however only run on the owning node as you agreed with. Thanks again for your time.